Get DataCard Variable Info - SOLIDWORKS PDM API
I want to develop a C# application using the Solidworks PDM API.
I want this application to modify some variables on the data card of a file that is currently open in the PDM interface and then save the changes to the data card.
At this point, how can I read the data card details of the part that is currently open in the PDM interface?
Thank you.
I can only access data card variables for files when I specify a specific file path.
